# Unable to copy the files to /system/app

Tags: file-system, mount, system, aosp

I am working on i.MX 6Quad SABRE-SD with **Android 9**. I am facing some problem when copy the some data to system/app from USB Mass Storage,

I got error, when I mount the system to write access:

```
sabresd_6dq:/ # **mount -o remount,rw '/system'**

**EXT4-fs (dm-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl,inode_readahead_blks=8**
```

And also I got error when copy the some data to system/app from USB Mass Storage.

```
sabresd_6dq:/system/app # cp /mnt/media_rw/2A61-DD07/ota/update.zip  /system/app

EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757: group 11, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 32768 vs 0 free clusters

EXT4-fs (dm-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected

Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost async page write

Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 1, lost async page write
```

Comment: Why are you using device-mapper with `/system`? `dm-crypt`? `dm-verity`? Or something else?

Comment: Is there any possible to disable dm-crypt and dm-verity?

Comment: Disabling is the next step. I don't know what and why are you using. I'm asking you. From where did you get `system.img` and kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration to unmount the system,

1. adb shell
2. reboot bootloader
3. fastboot oem unlock

Reboot the devices,

4. adb root
5. adb disable-verity
6. adb root
7. adb reboot
8. adb root
9. adb remount
10. adb push adb push 'D:\VINOTH'   /system/app/

Wait until finish

11. adb reboot